# maven build goal need to specify

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have extracted a sample Struts 2 project and it has the maven pom.xml file. I already installed the m2e plugin for eclipse. But when I right click the pom.xml file and select Maven Build it gives me the below error.

> No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid
>   lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or
>   :[:]:.
>   Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize,
>   generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources,
>   process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources,
>   process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources,
>   test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package,
>   pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify,
>   install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy, pre-clean,
>   clean, post-clean. -> [Help 1]

What is the goal I need to specify in the m2e window when I click on Maven build?

Answer (score 36):

You can build a maven project with m2e by right-clicking your project or your `.pom`, selecting `Run as` then `Maven build...` then write `package` into the goal field and click `Run`.

The according keyboard shortcut is `Alt+Ctrl+X`, then `m` - it will get you to the same dialog.

The result will probably be a `.war` file in the `target` subfolder of your project.

Answer (score 27):

In your Eclipse, Run-->Run Configurations --> on left you will see "Maven Build".on right please mention your goal in the goals tab.
for eg:**-Dmaven.tomcat.port=8080 tomcat:run**

Comment: Upvoted: This goal launches the maven web application on tomcat on port 8080 which is what I was trying to do.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer, as this gives the correct solution to what the OP asked.

Comment: Definitely should be the accepted answer as it directly solve the problem.

Answer (score 16):

In the `goal` field on `Run Configurations` dialog (`Main` tab), you can input any of the following `Maven's phases`:

---

1. **validate** – validate the project is correct and all necessary information is available
2. **compile** – compile the source code of the project
3. **test** – test the compiled source code using a suitable unit testing framework. These tests should not require the code to be packaged or deployed
   package – take the compiled code and package it in its distributable format, such as a JAR.
4. **integration-test** – process and deploy the package if necessary into an environment where integration tests can be run
5. **verify** – run any checks to verify the package is valid and meets quality criteria
6. **install** – install the package into the local repository, for use as a dependency in other projects locally
7. **deploy** – done in an integration or release environment, copies the final package to the remote repository for sharing with other developers and projects.

---

From: [Unknown Lifecycle Phase Error in Maven Build](http://www.javabeat.net/maven-lifecycle-phase-error/).

Answer (score 1):

after testing the above solutions I found the correct one.

(1) make sure are enviroment variables are well set (M2_HOME=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.3.3

M2=%M2_HOME%\bin)(https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_environment_setup.htm)

(2) open the command prompt as admin

(3) change directory  to your workspace (cd/workspace/project folder

(4) finally (customize)

mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=fr.myGroupId -DartifactId=MyApplication -Dpackagename=fr.myGroupId -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart
.