# What is the 'goal' here?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am trying to create my first ever Spring Boot application.  The `pom.xml` that I am using here is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>me.hahaha</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringBootTutorial</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <!-- <name>SpringBootTutorial</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url> -->

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- JUnit -->    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Boot Dependency -->
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

However, eclipse complains saying:

> No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format `<plugin-prefix>:<goal>` or `<plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>`. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]

I wonder what `goal` should my project have.

At this point, all *I* want is the project to build, compile and run and get the "Congratulations from BlogController.java" message on the localhost.  I believe this isn't something specific to the project either (because it doesn't do anything much) and the `pom.xml` that I have posted above is pretty similar to the one they give in the [docs for Maven](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/).

Thanks.

Note: In case required, the tutorial that I am trying to follow is [here](https://github.com/salisuwy/building-spring-boot-resp-api-v1).

Comment: watching a few videos on how to use your ide will help.  pom.xml, right click....run as maven install.

Comment: @tgkprog, true indeed.  I will do that now.  Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal you are looking for is `package`, which builds the executable package for your application.

Whenever you run maven with a goal every preceding goal is also executed. For a reference on which goal does what, see [the official maven guide on the build lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

Comment: Thank you.  That did the trick.  Even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12948760/8600195) was helpful.  Could you please let me know what package is?  Shouldn't it be the _name_ of the package, etc?  Why just the word `package`?

Comment: Just the word `package`. The `goal` is your intent as the developer when invoking maven, and at this point your intent is to package your application into an executable.

Comment: However, when I go to localhost, it doesn't show me the welcome message.  Why so?

Comment: You need a server to host your application, even when serving from localhost. I suggest you take a look at http://tomcat.apache.org/ for a free and easy to use development server.

Comment: Yes, I am aware about that.  What I am saying is, isn't the application deployed on Tomcat by default as per [this](https://medium.com/@salisuwy/building-a-spring-boot-rest-api-a-php-developers-view-part-i-6add2e794646) tutorial?  They are not doing anything specific for Tomcat.

Comment: When developing a project on an IDE such as IntelliJ, which that tutorial refers to, the IDE tends to hide multiple steps of the build process. In this case, the IDE sets up maven so the `deploy` goal copies the built executable to the tomcat directory, and invokes that instead of the aforementioned `package`. See this question for how to set it up manually https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824096/how-to-deploy-war-with-maven-to-tomcat

Comment: Oh, okay.  Actually I am referring this link: https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications and it says that presence of a _controller application_ is enough for Maven to detect and create an instance of Tomcat.

Comment: Have you tried running the jar built by `maven package` with `java -jar <name of your jar>.jar` ?

Comment: No.  Where do I run the command?  The console does not allow me to type anything.  It shows messages like 'Build successful'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169039/discussion-between-renanb-and-j-doe).